# Javascript comprobar vector aleatorio

Tags: javascript

Saludos, he creado una función en Js que cuando el usuario **introduce los números funciona perfectamente**, pero cuando esa función es llamada pero en vez de introducir los números, se han generado aleatorios no funciona, sale un " undefined " :

```
 function comenzar(){

         var numeritos = document.formu.elements["num[]"];
         var correcto = Comprobaciones(numeritos);

         if(correcto){
             maquina_boleto();
         }

    }

function Comprobaciones(numeritos){

          var correcto=true;

          for ( var i = 0 ; i < numeritos.length; i ++){
               if(numeritos[i].value < 1 || numeritos[i].value > 49){  
                            numeritos[i].value="";
                            correcto=false;
                }
             for(var j = i +1 ; j < numeritos.length;j++){
                 if(numeritos[i].value == numeritos[j].value){
                      numeritos[j].value="";
                      correcto=false;
                      alert("se repite el" + numeritos[i].value + " j vale" +  numeritos[j].value );
                 }
             }
         }

         return correcto;
      }
```

Hasta aquí todo va bien, comprueba y corrige los repetidos.
pero cuando lo hago que se haga aleatorio :

```
 function maquina_boleto(){

            var maq=[];
            var correcto=true;

            for(var i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
                    maq[i] =  Math.floor((Math.random()*20)) +1;
            }

        alert("vector maq >");
        alert(maq);


        for(var i = 0 ; i < maq.length;i++){
            do{
                correcto =  Comprobaciones(maq);
                if(!correcto) {
                    maq[i]= Math.floor((Math.random()*20)) +1;
                }
            }while(!correcto);

         alert("vector maq 2 >");
         alert(maq);
         }
    }
```

Cuando lleno el vector de aleatorios y llamo a la función comprobaciones entra en el if porque el numeritos[i].value VALE UNDEFINED y la numeritos[j].value VALE UNDEFINED y se queda en un bucle infinito.

Pueden Ayudarme ? Gracias

Comment: En vez de **maq[i] =  Math.floor((Math.random()*20)) +1;** usa **maq[i].value =  Math.floor((Math.random()*20)) +1;**

Comment: No sigue la ejecución con eso :(

Comment: Creo q deberias cambiar la logica del 2 for no usar y do while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el el Array `numeritos` cuando lo cargas aleatoriamente es un Array de enteros. Los enteros no tienen la propiedad `value` por eso `numeritos[i].value` te devuelve `undefined`.

En cambio cuando cargas desde el formulario, la variable `numerito` es un [HTML Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) cuyos elementos *si* tienen la propiedad `value`

Comment: Justo era eso, muchas gracias por responder y tu tiempo !!

Comment: Excelente que te haya servido. No olvides aceptar la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: cómo se hace eso ???